# Visual Studio 2022 Publish Not Working for Desktop application

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

When I try to publish
This type of error:
An error occurred trying to load the page.
The publish components are not available. You need to reinstall Visual Studio to publish your application.